# Qual è il significato di "acciso" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> A Ellis Island gli americani ti rifilano una serie di domande – una specie di interrogatorio. L’interprete – un tizio perfido, un vero **acciso** che deve aver fatto carriera esercitando il proprio zelo contro i suoi compatrioti – ti spiega che devi dire la verità, solo la verità, perché in America la menzogna è il peccato piú grave, peggio del furto.

In questa [*Grammatica diacronica del napoletano*](https://books.google.es/books?id=jsHJnzvJHxAC&pg=PA668&lpg=PA668&dq=acciso+ucciso&source=bl&ots=wjpdRLu7_v&sig=CXRb68iK-JIxsySf0cKNTA5jOb4&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnrJvXkMbfAhUDtHEKHca8DvAQ6AEwB3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=acciso%20ucciso&f=false) appare "acciso" come "ucciso" e lo stesso si trova in questa [raccolta di proverbi napoletani](https://it.wikiquote.org/wiki/Proverbi_napoletani). Tuttavia, non mi pare che questo sia il senso di questo vocabolo nel brano sopra citato. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "acciso" in questo passaggio?

Comment: L'unica accezione che trovo la dà Treccani, inteso come [soggetto passivo dell'accisa](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tag/ACCISO/) (cioè di un'imposta indiretta).
A sua volta, accisa viene dal latino medievale "accisia", deriv. di accidĕre ‘tagliare’. Non saprei però trovare un sinonimo.

Answer (score 3):

Letteralmente significa "ucciso" in dialetto napoletano ed in questo contesto vuol dire "degno di essere ucciso" in quanto "spietato", "crudele".

Spesso ho sentito dire anche "muort'acciso" riferito a persone vive, ma a cui si augura la morte peggiore in quanto "maledette", "spietate".

Il [Dizionario Napoletano-Italiano](https://books.google.it/books?id=2zUTAAAAQAAJ&q=acciso&dq=acciso&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRvdyE7pXtAhWMLewKHWvAA304FBDoATACegQIAhAC#v=snippet&q=acciso&f=false) lo traduce come "quasi degno di essere ucciso, capestro" (quindi io provo a interpretare, collegandomi al testo riferito, "che impone condizioni molto dure", "crudele"):

> Chill'acciso de maritemo - Quel capestro di mio marito

Comment: Infatti, potrebbe rientrare (come sinonimo) nell'accezione numero 4 della [voce "capestro" del GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000687.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Azzardo l'ipotesi che "acciso" significhi proprio "ucciso" e sia un modo per descrivere l'aspetto della persona, che immagino sia repellente, cadaverico.

Espressioni più usate potrebbero essere *"morto che cammina"* ,  *"zombi"*, *"cadavere ambulante"*

Ho anche il sospetto che l'aggettivo venga usato per dare un giudizio poco lusinghiero della persona in oggetto: viene descritto come *"perfido"* e che (ha) *"fatto carriera esercitando il proprio zelo contro i suoi compatrioti"*, quindi attirerà le stesse simpatie di un morto vivente.